# How to build a Low Poly on a High Poly while being able to see both?

Tags: 3d-view, shaders, wireframe, visibility

All the view options I can find make it hard to see the low poly mesh and the high poly mesh at the same time. (This is for baking a high poly onto a low poly) Is there something I'm missing?

This would be the best case options for me:

- X-Ray mode only on selected objects
- wireframe only for selected but with backfaces wires hidden
- high poly regular shaded with no transparency
- selected objects wires on top but slightly transparent where they are inside the high poly (not selected meshes)

[image]

Answer (score 1):

#### Lowpoly occluded wire with Highpoly surface

- X-Ray disabled
- Lowpoly *Viewport Display*

  - **In Front** enabled
  - *Display As* **Wire**

[image: low poly wire]

#### Standard X-Ray with occlusion

The lowpoly wires stay visible even if the surface is not visible.

[image: xray]

Notable options to combine:

- Overlays > Shading > Hidden Wire
- Viewport Shading > Outline (off)

Comment: I understand that these combinations don't fullfill all of your requirements, but I hope they're a start.