# Subdivision modifier hides points and edges in edit mode

Tags: edit-mode, visibility

[image: Hidden point and edges]

I added a subdivision modifier. While in edit mode edges and points are now sometimes hidden by the subdivided surface. Obviously I need to see points and edges always. Is there a way to turn this on?

Comment: You can try [x-ray](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/177924/30849) or enable "show subdivision in edit mode" in the modifier settings (small buttons of the modifier header

Comment: X-ray works quite well. Is there a way to have x-ray per object. So only the object that is currently in edit mode should have xray, the other object not.

Answer (score 0):

Try *On Cage* adjust edit cage to modifier result. In the header of modifier, it is a small button looks like inverted triangle.
[image: On Cage example]
*X-ray* might be better for simple structures. You can hide other objects by enabling *local view*, the default shortcuts are *'/' and 'numpad /'*.

Comment: Thanks for the posts. This is not a regular forum, according to site rules [links to answers are not answers](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2382) if the link goes missing your answer becomes an empty shell without content. Answers should be substantial and stand on their own without relying on external data like links, videos or images. Instead of having users go through external links, either transcribe essential parts of the process here, linking the source, or posts these in the comments section instead.